# Cannot get inappbrowser to work with location

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I cannot get the cordova inappbrowser to work properly with the location=yes. And without it I have no back button to get back into the app.
All I get is Unknown - Use Precise location.

```
<a href="http://www.google.ie" rel="external" target="_blank"  onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ie' ,'_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;">Link</a>
```

xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.1.0" />
```

Any ideas?.

I think the 'Unknown - Use Precise location' might be part of the google website and not the plugin. But that means I still have no back button :(

Comment: What platform?  Have a tried a different one to see if it acts similarly?

Comment: Hi Lou. Maybe I did not install it correctly? From the video I understood that I just have to add the line to the xml config and then do the onclick. Are there any other javascript files or anything else I need to add to my folders?

Comment: Just incase you are wondering, I am using build.phonegap.com to build and this is for ios and android

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did find an answer, well two answers.

1) added a one second wait to the code so that everything else loads before the map.
2) added a button 'behind' the map so that if it does not load you can click on 'show the map'

But generally the one second pause works well.

Comment: but it might not be relevant / needed any more as this was a long time ago and there might have been something else in my code causing it.